# Asp.Net Core v3.1 & Angular8 Azure SignalR with withAutomaticReconnect 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, azure-signalr

I am using Asp.Net Core 3.1 and Angular8 with Azure SignalR. It connect with azure signalr successfully. But some times it show this message.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your SignalR hub timeouts some operation and it drops the connection. This is not handled with the "withAutomaticReconnect" since this only reconnects in scenarios like, internet network switch and not hub/client errors.

What you can do is:

> Handle by you own when the the disconnected happens by an error.
>
> Try set more time for the `ClientTimeoutInterval` and the `KeepAliveInterval`.

Comment: Is there any estimated time for ClientTimeoutInterval and the KeepAliveInterval?